# How to align content to bottom of printed page?

Tags: css, printing

On the picture there's a print preview of a HTML page.

I would like to align the content after "Payment due date" on the next page in case the whole content is breaking a new page (like it is in this case).

Do I need to do jQuery magic here before printing in order to achieve this or is it possible with CSS?

Basically, I would like the content after "Payment due date" to be a fixed footer, but - if it's breaking a page, I need it to appear in the next A4 page.

So in this case, I would need it to appear in the next A4 page at the bottom (as a footer).

[image]

Comment: You can define different css rule sets for different media. For example for printout. This is documented.

Comment: I know that. What I don't know is how to achieve what I described above, on the CSS level.

Comment: if you want to put the elements after a section in an extra page, you have to try `style="page-break-after: always"` I don't know I you tried this one or not?! an in the next page you can set an absolute positioning for your extra code which is to be set in the other page!!
If possible, provide us with your code to show you how it works

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have tried this one:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
<div class="extra-content" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;"></div>
```